# Acronyms like \ac and \acs with no hyperlink

Tags: acronyms

I want to use acronym package for acronyms. And for that I use `\ac` and `\acs` in text and `\caption` or `\section`. However, in `\caption` and `\section` I don't want hyperlinks to the acronym table, but only in the text.

Therefore, is there a way to define new two commands based on `\ac` and `\acs` that when used do not make hyperlink, but work in the same behavior as the previous ones and includes the acronyms in the table of acronym?

Probably part of the code of `acronyms.sty` shall be used for that. But I do not know where to start.

Comment: I want really disable then, that way they will not appear when I use \tableofcontents (and so on), but will appear in the list of acronyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a ‘caption’ sibling of `\acs` as follows:

```
\protected\def\cacs{%
  \let\AC@hyperlink\@secondoftwo
  \acs
}
```

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\protected\def\cacs{%
  \let\AC@hyperlink\@secondoftwo
  \acs
}

\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\cacs\acs
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{AA}{An Acronym}
\end{acronym}

\section{\cacs{AA}}

\end{document}
```

Analogously, you could define a ‘caption’ sibling of `\ac`. But, obviously, it’s advisable to use the context-independent commands `\acs`, `\acl` etc. in captions and section headings.